# Symantec LiveUpdate Location Based Bandwidth Throttling

Tags: bandwidth-control, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have been lumped with our Symantec Endpoint responsibilities, and would like to look at fixing a long term issue we've been having of LiveUpdate smashing the links to our smaller sites.

I've done a bit of digging around Symantec's site, but can't work out how to actually implement location based throttling of the LiveUpdate services.

I have the IP ranges of the smaller sites I'd like to use, and have entered them in as 'Locations', but do not know where to apply them (at the 'My Company' level?) and how to do it.

We're running the latest Symantec 12.1.4 (RU4).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's Symantec LiveUpdate that is using all your bandwidth? LiveUpdate is used for less than you might think in a default installation of Symantec Endpoint Protection.

If it's definition updates that are using the bandwidth then you can look at Group Update Providers, which act like a local proxy for definition updates, so the GUP downloads from the Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager, and the local clients download from the GUP. http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH93813 provides some best practices.

As far as I know there's no way of throttling bandwidth usage within SEP itself.